# onPress of ListItem capturing last element of the list for all elements when used with FlatList's renderItem

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

If i save the value of `item` in a variable called `item1` inside the `renderItem` property of react-native's `FlatList`, then the `FlatList` behaves weirdly. It always prints the last element of the list, instead of printing the element i selected

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { FlatList } from "react-native";
import {
  ListItem,
  Text,
  View,
} from 'native-base';

export default class AbsurdFlatList extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      callback: (data)=>{
        console.log(data);
      }
    };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <FlatList
          data={[1,2,3]}
          renderItem={ ({item}) => {
              return (
                  <ListItem button
                    onPress={()=>{
                      console.log("correct list", item);
                      this.state.callback({what:item});
                    }}
                  >
                      <Text>{item} </Text>
                  </ListItem>
              );
            }
          }
        />
        <FlatList
          data={[1,2,3]}
          renderItem={ ({item}) => {
            item1 = item;
              return (
                  <ListItem button
                    onPress={()=>{
                      console.log("wrong list", item1);
                      this.state.callback({what: item1});
                    }}
                  >
                      <Text>{item1} </Text>
                  </ListItem>
              );
            }
          }
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

In both FlatLists, output should be the same. 
But in one, i get, 1,2,3 while in the other i get 3,3,3 (always the last element)

```
ReactNativeJS ▶︎ 'correct list item', 1

ReactNativeJS ▶︎ 'correct list item', 2

ReactNativeJS ▶︎ 'correct list item', 3

ReactNativeJS ▶︎ 'wrong list item', 3

ReactNativeJS ▶︎ 'wrong list item', 3

ReactNativeJS ▶︎ 'wrong list item', 3
```

It shouldn't matter... that in the 2nd `FlatList` i saved `item` variable's value in `item1` variable before using it. 
And the crazy thing is, `item1` variable display correct value inside `<Text>` element but wrong value inside `<ListItem>` element.

This is the UI output for the code [image: ![preview](https://imgur.com/a/X2YaDIg)]

Answer (score 0):

One error is found in your code.

```
 item1 = item;
```

The price of **item** is given to **item1**.

Therefore, the value of **item1** becomes the **item** value. The value of the item you clicked last becomes the value of **item1**. If you look at the output code, the last `item value is 3`, so it is `all 3 output`.

This change will solve the problem.

```js
        renderItem={ ({item}) => {
              return (
                  <ListItem button
                    onPress={()=>{
                      console.log("wrong list", item);
                      this.state.callback({what: item});
                    }}
                  >
                      <Text>{item} </Text>
                  </ListItem>
              );
            }
```

Comment: The `<Text>` element does not take the last value. Only `console.log` does.
Why is that? Secondly, renderItem, is not called during onPress right? So, why is the last clicked value taken up by item1?

Comment: The first reason why the text is displayed in order is because you have not yet passed the value to the item. Items made on the flat list are drawn from the data you have. That is why the price is not the same.

Comment: RenderItem is not called when you press a button, but you are already assigning a value as a variable. That is why the last assigned value of 3 is the value of item1. That is why the console log shows that.

Comment: The value of item1 mentioned in OnPress is not the data value of the FlatList, but the value passed by the item becomes the parameter.

Comment: If my answer was helpful, would you check the 'V' and the arrows to select the my answer?

Comment: I'm sorry, i read your comments multiple times, but im not able to get what u r saying.
In my question, i have added 2 FlatLists. One behaves as expected, but the other weirdly.
Both of them render the same in UI. But differently when clicked.

In one FlatList, i have used `item` and in the other `item1`.

This is where the problem starts. `item1`'s value becomes "3" in console.log for all elements but not as "3" surprisingly in the `Text` elements.

Why does `item1` take up different values in different places inside the same function?

Answer (score 0):

It has been 3 years but if someone ends up here, the solution would be to do `const item1 = item;` instead of `item1 = item;` to "clear" the value in a loop like this.